# Yajra Datatables - Column Date Format

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

laravel 8 with yajra Datatables. The datatable is created well, but i need to custom some column data.

```
return [
            Column::computed('action')
                ->exportable(false)
                ->printable(false)
                ->width(60)
                ->addClass('text-center'),
            Column::make('id')
                ->title('ID'),
            Column::make('name')
                ->title('Nome Acabamento'),
            Column::make('enabled')
                ->title('Visível'),
            Column::make('created_at'),
            Column::make('updated_at'),
        ];
```

In this example i need the `created_at` to be date format (d-m-Y) and `id` to be a sum operation from id + 1000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it :

`->editColumn('created_at', function($data){ $formatedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data->created_at)->format('d-m-Y'); return $formatedDate; })`

Comment: Doesn't work in laravel 9 and dataTales 10

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 10, we use the following code for `dataTables10`.

```
 ->editColumn('created_at', function (Outcome $outcome) {
            return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($outcome->created_at )->isoFormat('DD.MM.YYYY');
        })
```

Comment: What is `Outcome`? I cannot find anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
For example case : 

->editColumn('end_date', function($model){
            $formatDate = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($model->end_date));
            return $formatDate;
        })
->addColumn('legal','{{$model->legals->name}}')
->rawColumns(['action'])
->toJson();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql and laravel 10 ,you can change format by mysql request

for example im working with document table and created_at column :

```
        ->addColumn('created_at_formatted', function ($document) {
            // Format the created_at column using MySQL date_format
            return $document->created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
            // Change the format as needed
        })
```

then add the column into your datatable

```
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        ['data' => 'created_at_formatted', 'name' => 'created_at_formatted', 'title' => 'Date'], // Add this line
    ];
}
```